# Adding function dynamical to angular objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dynamic

How to add a function to a angular object dynamical to the onclick or click event?

Adding onclick={{item.function}} or ng-click={{item.function}} won't work

JS

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.test = function() {
      alert(1);
    };
    $scope.items = {
      'item1': {
        name: 'Item1',
        function: 'test()' // Not calling
      }
    };
  }]);
```

Html

```
<html ng-app="app">
<body ng-controller="MainController">
  <ul ng-repeat="item in items">
    <li ng-bind="item.name" ng-click="item.function"></li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Not working demo
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqEKRP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In controller:

```
...
      'item1': {
        name: 'Item1',
        f: $scope.test
      }
...
```

In template:

```
<li ng-bind="item.name" ng-click="item.f()"></li>
```

http://codepen.io/bparnikel/pen/bpNjoE